# How can i resize a rotated rectangle with aspect ratio?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, rotation

I have an array of points

`PArr [0..3]`

which correspond to the rectangle points , i know how to rotate the rectangle around its center but i want to resize it after a rotation process of angle theta.

i searched on web but i didn't find an algorithm that works well for rotated rectangles 
Regarding that i resize it in Mouse Move  action.

How can i resize the points while keeping the aspect ratio of the rectangle sides, i know it's a vectors issue but i'm a bit confused about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transformation matrices. They provide clear multiple transforms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

In your case you need 4 matrices:

1. Translation `(-sizeX/2, -sizeY/2)` - to process further transformations around the center of the rectangle
2. Rotation by a specified angle
3. Scale by a specified factor (aspect ratio of the rectangle will be preserved!)
4. Translation `(sizeX/2, sizeY/2)` - to revert the first positioning

Multiply these 4 matrices and apply the result to your rectangle points. Oh, and your rectangle must have its origin in (0, 0) to apply the matrix. If the origin of your rectangle has (x0, y0) coordinates, use

`(-x0 - sizeX/2, -y0 - sizeY/2)` for the first matrix

and `(x0 + sizeX/2, y0 + sizeY/2)` for the fourth one

Comment: Do you mean the width  of the rectangle by sizeX?

Comment: Note that to handle translations in 2D you must use 3x3 affine matrices, and not the standard 2x2 linear transformations from that page.  It would be far simpler to handle the two translations as separate calculations and _not_ use 4 separate matrices.

Comment: Of course, the separate calculations are simpler, but IMO it's really important to understand how to obtain a desired transformation. After that you can easily optimize the transformation by manually converting matrices multiplication into simpler formulas.

Comment: To Sara: yes, I meant width and height of the rectangle

Comment: yes ,but do you know how to pass the scale value in mousemove action i dont know how to determine it,Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I want it like microsoft office when it rotate the image then resize it, it preserves the aspect ratio